# Releasing iPad-only update when you have universal app in TestFlight

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

Our application is currently available in App Store only for iPad, but we have a universal build (iPad + iPhone) available for testing in TestFlight. Is it possible to release an iPad-only update for our app? Or we have to submit universal build once we've uploaded universal application to TestFlight?

I know you cannot downgrade to a specific device version once you have universal app in App Store, but I guess this should work when your universal app is only in beta?

Comment: Did you try it? What happened?